# os.makedirs works when run in IDLE, fails in scheduled task

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have an ArcPy script that works when run in IDLE, but fails when run as a scheduled task. This is the problem section:

```
outPath = os.path.abspath(r"X:\GroupDirs\0731\GIS_CORE\PUPS")
log.write("Output path: {}\n".format(outPath))
try:
    outDir = os.path.join(outPath, "utiliquest{}".format(date))
    if not os.path.exists(outDir):
        os.makedirs(outDir)
    log.write("Created scratch and output")
except:
    fail_log(log)
```

When I run this in IDLE, it outputs correctly, makes the directory, and continues to execute.

```
Output path: X:\GroupDirs\0731\GIS_CORE\PUPS
Created scratch and output
```

When this runs as a scheduled task, the logfile has the correct directory, but the `os.makedirs(outDir)` command fails to execute:

```
Output path: X:\GroupDirs\0731\GIS_CORE\PUPS

     Failed at 09/24/14 14:41:45
PYTHON ERRORS:
Traceback info:
  File "C:\Batch Processes\IRTHnet\Batch_CopyData.py", line 64, in <module>
    os.makedirs(outDir)

Error Info:
[Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'X:\\'
```

This is being run on the same machine each time, so the X drive is pointing to the same location.

Why is this causing a failure, and what I can do to fix/circumvent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is being run on the same machine each time, so the X drive is pointing to the same location.

That doesn't follow. Drive mappings are per-session. If you've set up Window to restore your drive mappings at logon (which is what most people do, since at least in XP through 7 there's a checkbox for "Reconnect at logon" in the "Map Drive" dialog in Explorer), then the X drive won't be pointing to the same location unless you've logged on as the same user.

You *can* set up system-wide drive mappings that will be reconnected at startup instead of logon, but this isn't trivial (and may be different on different Windows versions), and it also leads to a mess of permissions issues that you really don't want to deal with.

See [Services and Redirected Drives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143(v=vs.85).aspx) at MSDN, which isn't *directly* what you're trying to do here, but does explain the issues pretty nicely and link to a lot of other useful documentation.

An alternative solution is to just use a UNC path, like `r'\\Server\share\GroupDirs\0731\GIS_CORE\PUPS'`. This isn't *always* appropriate (e.g., you might want to mount different shares to `X:` on different machines, and have your script always use whichever one is mounted to `X:`), but when it is, it's usually simplest.

Comment: Company policy is that the `X:` drive is always the `X:` for all users, but "unless you've logged on as the same user" was the key -- the scheduled task had been set up to run under a user that doesn't have permissions on that drive. Thanks!